# Incorrect syntax near '' C#

Tags: c#

I Get Error " `INCORRECT SYNTAX NEAR''`.

Here is my code :

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Mr\Documents\Student.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
cmd.CommandText = "insert into tblHesabdary(Shahriye Koll,Pardakhty,Mablagh,Naghdy - Shomare Fish,Albaghy,Name,Family)values(@SK,@P,@M,@NSF,@A,@N,@F)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SK", shahriye_KollTextBox.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P", pardakhtyTextBox.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@M", mablaghTextBox.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NSF", naghdy___Shomare_FishTextBox.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@A", albaghyTextBox.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@N", nameTextBox.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@F", familyTextBox.Text);
con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
MessageBox.Show("jj");
```

My Database is SQL Server Express.

Comment: Don't create columns with spaces as in `Naghdy - Shomare Fish`. You can always use aliases in your queries like: `SELECT NaghdyShomareFish AS  [Naghdy - Shomare Fish] FROM ...`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a column name or other identifier includes spaces or other special characters then it must be escaped:

```
insert into tblHesabdary([Shahriye Koll],Pardakhty,Mablagh,[Naghdy - Shomare Fish],Albaghy,Name,Family)values(@SK,@P,@M,@NSF,@A,@N,@F)
```

A better option is to not include special characters in the first place, e.g. name those columns `ShahriyeKoll` and `Naghdy_ShomareFish` or the like.